# Error al implementar generación aleatoria de números en C

Tags: c, linux, random

estoy haciendo el juego de los barquitos en C, y quiero hacer que la disposición de los barcos del jugador ordenador(se juega contra el ordenador), sea aleatoria. Para ello había pensado en generar números aleatorios y asignárselos a las coordenadas del tablero. Pruebo el algoritmo para generar los números en un archivo de prueba y todo funciona correctamente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    // Declaracion de variables
    int fila,i;
    int hora = time(NULL);
    //semilla de rand
    srand(hora);
    //ciclo generar 2 coordenadas
    for(i = 0; i<1; i++)
    {
           fila = rand()%10+1;
           printf("%d\n",fila);
    }
    return (fila);
}
```

Lo compilo y ejecuto sin ningún error, e imprime un número aleatorio.

Después de probarlo en este archivo suelto, decido ponerlo en el código de mi juego:

Primero declaro y le doy semilla a rand() de forma **global**, antes del main:

```
    int hora = time(NULL);
    //semilla rand()
    srand(hora);
```

Y esta es una de las funciones que debería generar un número aleatorio:

```
    int filaAle()
    {
         // Declaracion de variables
         int fila,i;
         //ciclo generar 2 coordenadas
         for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
         {
                fila = rand()%10+1;
                printf("%d\n",fila);
         }
         return fila;
    }
```

Al compilar, estos son los errores que me devuelve(abro los que tienen detalle):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como solucionar estos errores, y necesito poner esta característica en el trabajo.
**¿Hay alguna solución?**

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO** puedes llamar a las funciones `time()` y `srand()` ANTES del método `main`. Si quieres tener la variable `hora` como una variable global debes inicializarla con un valor constante. El estándar de [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) define en el 
punto 6.7.8 parágrafo 4:

> *All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.*
>
> Todas las expresiones en un inicializador de un objeto que tiene duración de almacenamiento estático [por ejemplo, las variables globales] deben ser expresiones constantes o literales de cadena.

Recuerda que en un programa en C la primera función que se invoca es `main` (salvo ciertas excepciones). Por lo tanto, tu código pretende invocar dos funciones antes de que la función `main` se ejecute.

Una posible solución es que obtengas la semilla para tu generador aleatorio dentro de la misma función que asignará los números aleatorios, evitando usar estas variables como globales -lo cual por otro lado es una muy mala práctica de programación-.

```
int filaAle() {

    //semilla rand()
    srand(time(NULL));
    // Declaracion de variables
    int fila,i;

    //ciclo generar 2 coordenadas
    for(i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        fila = rand()%10+1;
        printf("%d\n",fila);
    }

    return fila;
}
```

Comment: es importante hacer una solución del problema a traves de las claves que proporcionan los estandares sin embargo un metodo puede ser usado a traves de una variable de alcance global o local incluyendo que hay que respetar, valga la redundacia los estandares las funciones de cada una (methods)